# Identification and effected muscles of excercise

Tags: exercise, shoulders, arms

[image]

What is this excercise and which muscles it works out?

Comment: It hits back, mostly rhomboid muscle IIRC

Comment: Looks like "straight arm lat pulldown"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [straight arm lateral pulldown](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/exercises/straight-arm-lat-pull-down.html). It primarily targets the [latissimus dorsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latissimus_dorsi_muscle), but as it's a [compound exercise](https://www.acefitness.org/education-and-resources/professional/expert-articles/5811/5-benefits-of-compound-exercises) movement it will engage a variety of other muscles.

I'm not sure why this person is hinged at the hip, as most instructions I've seen this for have you vertical or mostly-vertical.

There are literally [dozens of variations on the pulldown](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt.html#Latissimus): seated, standing, with handles, with a bar, alternating one hand, kneeling, on one foot, etc. For a laugh, [check out this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJ3cRBcPU-Q).

Comment: Most likely due to a height limitation on the equipment. Hinging at the hip allows for a full overhead extension, and a fuller range of motion in the actual execution.

Comment: @JohnP I do it in same stlye, btw, i.e. not standing straight  - when staying straight I feel like my lower back part involved into work more, but with angle I feel like it hit rhomboids or smth near (but its individual thing anyway)